Java XSLT transfomer fails to execute with source XML has invalid schema
I have been banging my head with this for a while. I have a fairly simple XML:
<Result xmlns="http://invalid.schema.org/123">
    <Item>
        <id>123</id>
    </Item>
</Result>

and a straightforward identity transform with a simple change:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
        <xsl:copy>
            ***
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   
</xsl:stylesheet>

However when I run a java code to apply such transformation:
 StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(xsltFile);
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();    
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
            
StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(sourceFile);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(targetFile);
transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);

It simply won't transform the file.
However I noted that because the xml source has an invalid xmlns schema, if I remove it :
<Result>
    <Item>
        <id>123</id>
    </Item>
</Result>

Then the transformation works.
Does anyone have a clue on why is that? I could not find a way to disable validation/schema on the transformerFactory.
Thanks folks

You need to add xpath-default-namespace="http://invalid.schema.org/123" to the <xsl:stylesheet .... It is XSLT 2.0 and later functionality to handle a default namespace.

From the documentation of TransformerFactory.newTransformer:  “The Source is an XSLT document that conforms to XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 1.0.”  XSLT 2.0 is not currently supported.

Schema, valid or not, has nothing to do with this.

Thank you @YitzhakKhabinsky, that was the reason :) I didn't know I had to put the default schema there. Thanks
